# allowClear="true" not works in angular-ui select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select2

How to clear the selected value in [angular-ui select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select).
I want something like this [image]

Comment: Works for me. http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

Comment: thanks for the reply. but I want something like in the picture attached.

Comment: I tried this one http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

Comment: I've got similar problem. I have exactly same code as in above plnkr site, but the clear button does not show up. I'm using same version of select.js.

Answer (score 24):

You should define it in `select-match`

```
<ui-select-match allow-clear="true" placeholder="Select something">   
    {{$select.selected.name}}
</ui-select-match>
```